# Gcloud-ruby backoff on copying files and other operations

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-storage, gcloud-ruby

As far as I can tell [0] currently gcloud-ruby gem only does backoff on bucket operations, but I'm getting `Gcloud::Storage::ApiError: User Rate Limit Exceeded` on copying files, as far as I can tell there is no way currently to enable it for other operations and `Gcloud::Backoff` can't be reused in client code either, meaning one will have to resort to custom retry solution :(

[0] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-ruby/blob/master/lib/gcloud/storage/connection.rb#L77

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work on the gcloud gem. When we first implemented the incremental backoff we asked the Storage team which API calls should be retried. This is why only some of the calls have that code. If you [open an issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-ruby/issues/new) for this we will apply the backoff to all the API calls.